# Heroku Application Error - code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: heroku, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a dash app on heroku.

Everything works fine (also locally) except from when I run `heroku open` I get this Application Error:

[image]

`heroku logs --tail` then gives:

```
2019-11-22T22:55:41.598239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-11-22T22:55:41.587218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-11-22T22:55:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-11-22T22:55:59.485489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=romania2019.herokuapp.com request_id=d48fde4a-bd7e-47e2-9a21-bdf589ef281a fwd="152.115.83.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-22T22:55:59.851491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=romania2019.herokuapp.com request_id=b6bbb5e8-8667-42f2-b083-b7bf26b5ae14 fwd="152.115.83.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any suggestions where I should look next?

---

Here is my `app.py` I am trying to deploy:

```py
import datetime
import time

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://prezenta.bec.ro/prezidentiale24112019/abroad-precincts'


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
                       "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",1)


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

# Find button and click on it
ELEMENT = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/h2')

def update(ELEMENT):
    # time.sleep(2.9)
    return int(ELEMENT.text.replace('.', ''))


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('ROMANIA - Presidential Elections Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=60*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)

time.sleep(5)
@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_metrics(n):
    no = update(ELEMENT)
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Voters: {}'.format(no), style=style),
        html.Span('Voters/Min: {}'.format(np.diff(data['number'])[-5:].mean()), style=style)
    ]


data = {'time': [], 'number': []}

# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph_live(n):
    # Collect some data
    data['time'].append(datetime.datetime.now()) # + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3))

    try:
        no = update(ELEMENT)
        data['number'].append(no)
    except:
        data['number'].append(no)



    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.1)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['number'],
        'name': 'Voters',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': np.diff(data['number']),
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Voters / Min',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)
    fig.layout.update(height=800, )

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

It basically reads the number of voters and displays the number of votes per minute.

And the deployment instructions I've been following are given here: https://dash.plot.ly/deployment.

Comment: Same error here, still can't find a solution..

Comment: why no answers to this one

Answer (score 0):

open your git bash and post
log --tails it will show your the error type H10 is app crasing due to some error missing dependencies or your procfiles is not well set so try reading the error types and look in your code. if your app is working fine in your local host try
web: gunicorn index:server --preload --timeout60.